# How to access command line arguments in Spring configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a Spring Boot application that uses a Spring Integration Stored Procedure Inbound Channel Adapter. I would like to pass a command line argument to the stored procedure. The Spring Boot doc says that SpringApplication will convert any command line option arguments starting with ‘--’ to a property and add it to the Spring Environment. What is the correct way to access this property in the int-jdbc:parameter element?

Application.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplication("integration.xml").run(args);
        System.out.println("Hit Enter to terminate");
        System.in.read();
        ctx.close();
    }    
}
```

integration.xml

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter
    stored-procedure-name="sp_get_some_records"
    data-source="dataSource"
    channel="recs.in.channel"
    id="recs.in">

    <int:poller fixed-rate="86400" time-unit="SECONDS" />

    <int-jdbc:parameter name="myarg" type="java.lang.Integer" value="${arg1}" />

</int-jdbc:stored-proc-inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Using `${arg1}` here doesn't seem to get resolved. What is the proper syntax, or do I need to define an additional property or property placeholder?

Starting the app, e.g. with `java -jar app.jar --arg1=5` throws an exception of

```
Error converting typed String value for bean property 'value'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Integer]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${arg1}"
```

I thought first it had to do with type conversion and tried with

```
<int-jdbc:parameter name="myarg" type="java.lang.Integer" value="#{ T(java.lang.Integer).parseInt(arg1) }" />
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: what values did you pass in the command line?

Comment: I tried e.g. --arg1=5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any Spring Boot stuff.

I mean `auto-configuration`, which includes `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, too.

That must be something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("integration.xml")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("Hit Enter to terminate");
        System.in.read();
        ctx.close();
    }    
}
```

I've just checked with our `barrier` sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/barrier

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include that part of my Application.java. I updated my original post. I do have `@SpringBootApplication` before the Application class.

Comment: It doesn't matter, because your `SpringApplication("integration.xml").run(args)` doesn't know about that `@Configuration` class. IT must be included as a `source`, too: `new SpringApplication(Application.class, "integration.xml")`

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would convert your XML config to JavaConfig.  Then you could just access your property in your config class using

```
@Value("${arg1}")
private Integer arg1;
```

Comment: Not familiar with JavaConfig, I was hoping to find a solution that works with my existing xml configuration.